# Modelform 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to save a boolean field in a model form. I get the type error 'bool' object is not iterable and I'm not quite sure why. I stupidly assumed django just handled the fact that the boolean value is saved as a string in the database(PostgreSQL) because it did successfully after a signal saved it initially after a new user signed up. After a bit of research and trial and error, I'm at loss here. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
class SundayBoolAvailable(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                   default='',
                                   related_name='teacher_bool_available_id')
    sunday_bool = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)


class SundayTime(models.Model):
    teacher_id_time = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        default='',
                                        related_name='teacher_time_available_id')
    sun_from_hour = models.TimeField(choices=HOUR_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    sun_to_hour = models.TimeField(choices=HOUR_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teacher_id)

class SundayBoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sunday_bool = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SundayBoolAvailable
        fields = ['sunday_bool', ]

    #        widgets = {
    #            'sunday': forms.HiddenInput(),
    #        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SundayBoolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sunday_bool'].required = False


class SundayTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SundayTime
        fields = ['sun_to_hour', 'sun_from_hour']


#        widgets = {
#            'sunday': forms.HiddenInput(),
#        }

SundayInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MyUser, SundayTime, form=SundayTimeForm, extra=0,
                                            can_delete=True, min_num=0, validate_min=True, max_num=3, validate_max=True,
                                            fields=['sun_to_hour', 'sun_from_hour'])

@login_required()
@teacher_required
def availability_update_view(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    sun_obj = get_object_or_404(MyUser, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sun_bool = SundayBoolForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=sun_obj)
        sunday_formset = SundayInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=sun_obj, prefix='id_sunday_formset')
        if all(sun_bool.is_valid() and sunday_formset.is_valid()):
            sun_bool_instance = sun_bool.save(commit=False)

            # I feel there is something missing here?

            sun_bool_instance.save()

            sunday_formset.save()
            messages.success(request, f'You have successfully updated your availability!')
            return redirect('teacher_profile')

    else:

        sun_bool = SundayBoolForm(instance=sun_obj)
        sunday_formset = SundayInlineFormSet(instance=sun_obj, prefix='id_sunday_formset')

    context = {
        'sun_bool': sun_bool, 'sunday_formset': sunday_formset
    }

    return render(request, 'appointment/availability_update_new.html', context)


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_sunday_appointment_bool(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        SundayBoolAvailable.objects.get_or_create(teacher_id=instance)

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/availability_update_new.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="button" class="sun-not-available" value="Not Available Sunday" onclick="sunCheckOne(); sunHideShow()"
           id="sun-not-available">
    <form id="all-add-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="sunday-all" id="sunday-all-id">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <legend class="bottom mb-4">Profiles Info</legend>
            <div class="sun-bool">
                {{ sun_bool.sunday_bool }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ sunday_formset.management_form }}
        {% for sun_form in sunday_formset %}
            {% for hidden in sun_form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="sun_time_slot_form">

                {{ sun_form }}

                <button class="delete-sun-form" type="button" id="delete-sun-btn" onclick=""> Delete This
                    Sunday
                    Timeslot
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button id="add-sun-form" type="button" class="button">Add Other Sunday Times</button>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/add_timeslot.js' %}"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
{% endblock content %}


Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/availability_update_new/3/

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mysite',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'appointments.apps.TeacherAppointmentConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'imagekit',
 'compressor',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled7\appointments\views.py", line 111, in availability_update_view
    if all(sun_bool.is_valid() and sunday_formset.is_valid()):

Exception Type: TypeError at /availability_update_new/3/
Exception Value: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback, explain what you try to do.

Comment: Just wondering why it won't validate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if all(sun_bool.is_valid() and sunday_formset.is_valid()):
    # …
    pass
```

with:

```
if sun_bool.is_valid() and sunday_formset.is_valid():
    # …
    pass
```

[**`all(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) takes an iterable and checks if all items have truthiness `True`. But here you have a single boolean.

Comment: I had that but the value didn't change in the database. That's why I wrote myself a note after validation. I am quite confused about this problem. I thought it would be quite forward but apparently not.

Comment: @Wideback: why do you use `commit=False`.

Comment: @Wideback: but regardless, using `all` only makes matters worse, since now the `if` condition raises an error, so stops the code flow.

Comment: If condition doesn't raise an error but no change of the database after submitting the form.

Comment: @Wideback: well likely because of the `commit=False` which does not save m2m's for example.

Comment: I was hoping that was it but I added that after I tried to find a solution to the original problem of the bool not saving to the database.

Comment: @Wideback: but you pass as instance `nstance=sun_obj`, which is a `MyUser`, hence you will *not* edit any `SundayBoolAvailable`, but a `MyUser`...